# Default post tab showing twice in admin bar

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, admin-bar

I have to re-register WordPress default post type to change the post slug to "blog", changing permalink structure was not worked for me as it rewrite custom post types slugs also. So I used below code in my `function.php`:

```
function my_new_default_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'post', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
    ),
    'public'  => true,
    '_builtin' => false,
    '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'blog' ),
    'query_var' => false,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
) );
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_new_default_post_type', 1 );
```

It worked fine and satisfied my need. But the issue is now it showing "post" item twice in the admin bar. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

you may try to de-register/unset default post type and register post type with your requirements.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'unset_default_post' ) ) :
function unset_default_post( ) {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $post_type = 'post';
    if ( isset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type ] ) ) {
        unset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type ] );
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
endif;
```

Comment: have tried this, but not worked :(